# How to write sub query in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two tables `users` and `posts` and they have association of `has_many`. I want to fetch details of both `users` and `posts` in a single query. I'm able to manage the sql query but I don't want to use the raw query in the code (using `execute` method) as i think it is kind of simple thing and can be written using active record.

Here is the sql query

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.timestamp, b.id, b.user_id, b.title
FROM users a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, user_id, title, from, to FROM posts) b on b.user_id = a.id
where id IN ( 1, 2, 3);
```

I think `includes` does not help here because i'm dealing with large data.
Can any one help me ?

Comment: The `where id` part - do you mean `a.id` or `b.id` should be included the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want those specific columns and nothing else then this will work

```
User.joins(:post)
 .where(id: [1,2,3])
 .select("users.id, users.name, users.timestamp, 
          posts.id as post_id, posts.user_id as post_user_id, 
          posts.title as post_title")
```

This will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `User` objects with virtual attributes for `post_id`, `post_user_id` (Not sure why you need this one since you already selected `users.id`), and `post_title`.

The query produced will be

```
   SELECT users.id, 
          users.name, 
          users.timestamp, 
          posts.id as post_id,
          posts.user_id as post_user_id, 
          posts.title as post_title
   FROM users
   INNER JOIN posts on posts.user_id = users.id
   where users.id IN ( 1, 2, 3);
```

Please note you may have multiple `User` objects, one for each `Post`, just as the SQL query does.

You can execute your exact query using the string version of `joins` e.g.

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT id, user_id, title, from, to FROM posts) b on b.user_id = users.id")
 .where(id: [1,2,3])
 .select("users.id, users.name, users.timestamp, 
          b.id as post_id, b.user_id as post_user_id, 
          b.title as post_title")
```

Additionally to avoid some of the overhead you can use `arel` instead e.g.

```
 users_table = User.arel_table
 posts_table = Post.arel_table

 query = users_table.project(Arel.star)
           .join(posts_table)
             .on(posts_table[:user_id].eq(users_table[:id]))
           .where(users_table[:id].in([1,2,3]))
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query.to_sql)
```

This will return an `ActiveRecord::Result` with 2 useful methods `columns` (the columns selected) and `rows`. You can convert this to a `Hash`(`#to_hash`) but note that any columns with duplicate names (`id` for instance) will overwrite one another.

You could fix this by specifying the colums you want selected in the `project` portion. e.g. your current query would be:

```
query =  users_table.project(
    users_table[:id],
    users_table[:name],
    users_table[:timestamp],
    posts_table[:id].as('post_id'),
    posts_table[:user_id].as('post_user_id'),
    posts_table[:title].as('post_title')
).join(posts_table)
   .on(posts_table[:user_id].eq(users_table[:id]))
.where(users_table[:id].in([1,2,3]))

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query.to_sql).to_hash
```

Since none of the names collide now it can be structured into a nice `Hash` where the keys are the column names and the values or the row value for that record.

Comment: I have already tried this one. the thing is this works but it is slower than the query i have written in the question.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza this is the most railsy way to handle your request. I will update with a way to execute your exact query (using raw SQL)

Comment: Yeah i agree with you but in reality i require lots of attributes in the select statement and the data is large and is going to be increased.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza well it is difficult to help if you do not specify what "lots" and "large" mean. Maybe look into a pagination technique or `ActiveRecord::Base#find_in_batches` Also if the `where` clause is going to be large we can certainly convert that to a subquery and if you do not need true active record objects I can speed it up quite a bit by using `arel` directly

Comment: Yes the pagination helps here. Also lots means i need to work with approximately every column of both the tables exception few.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza in that case selecting them is overkill unless those "few" are blob (memo) columns that store alot of data. I think your problem is the shear amount of data and the overhead of mapping them into AR objects. I am not certain that your question actually targets the root of your problem. Do you need the Active Record objects or just the data as say a `Hash`?

Comment: I think the query that you have written in the end should work for me. But i would like to know what other options do i have ? As of now, after getting the response in the controller, i'm using a ruby class to map the result into the type of hash i want to return as a response.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza See update using `arel`. This will get you to a `Hash` immediately so restructuring to an API response might be easier from here and there is no over head in mapping everything into true ActiveRecord objects. This is the way I prefer to handle queries for data reporting to spreadsheets and charts as it basically returns a table. Additionally `arel` will handle the sanitizing and escaping that raw SQL will not

Comment: Nice. This is clean !

Answer (score 2):

```
users = User.joins(:posts).includes(:posts).where(id: [1, 2, 3])
```

Will give you all the users with theirs posts.

then you can do whatever you want with them, but to access posts data for first retrieved user

`first_user_posts = users.first.posts # this will not make additional DB queries as you used includes and data is already added`

- We use `joins` to have `INNER JOIN` statement in the SQL
- We use `includes` to load all `posts` in the memory

Comment: includes saves the data into memory which is not a very good thing when you are dealing with large data.

Comment: What difference does `joins` and `includes` in a single statement make ?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes - it includes the data of the related table into the result set, i.e. in your case makes sure that your posts data are included

Comment: @Ahmadhamza the `joins` will just force the INNER JOIN rather than the native OUTER JOIN that `includes` uses. Also this will execute 2 queries because `includes` needs to have a reference to in the query or the data will not be loaded in the first query. adding `references(:posts)` will load all the data in the first query.

Answer (score 1):

> I have two tables users and posts and they have association of
>   has_many. I want to fetch details of both users and posts in a single
>   query.

can be done with includes like

```
users = User.includes(:posts).where({posts: {user_id: [1,2,3]}})
```

other is `eager_load` and `preload` you can use as per your requirements, for more https://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/